# Can't initialize my-date-picker input to current date using reactive forms

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-reactive-forms

I'm using MyDatePickerModule (https://github.com/kekeh/mydatepicker), and want to initialize my date picker to the current date. I'm using reactive forms.

I followed this https://github.com/kekeh/mydatepicker/wiki/Initialize-with-selDate-attribute

but it is still not working.

this is the template section:

```
<my-date-picker
  id="myDate"
  name="myDate"
  [options]="myDatePickerOptions"
  formControlName="myDate">
</my-date-picker>
```

myComponent.ts:

```
public todayDateToMyDatePicker(){
let d: Date = new Date();
return {year: d.getFullYear(),
  month: d.getMonth() + 1,
  day: d.getDate()};
 }
```

In init form method:

```
this.myForm= this.builder.group({
  myDate: [this.todayDateToMyDatePicker()]
})
```

Comment: It works now ! I just changed formControlName to  [formControl] and initialize it to current date in your form initialization.

Answer (score 1):

```
ngOnInIt() {
  this.updateValue();
}


updateValue() {
this.myForm.patchValue({
      myDate: this.todayDateToMyDatePicker()
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you describe how your answer is a solution to the original question? It will help when people search and find this answer.